# Hide/Show Column in a HTML Table

Tags: jquery, html, hide, html-table, show

I have an HTML table with several columns and I need to implement a column chooser using jQuery.  When a user clicks on a checkbox I want to hide/show the corresponding column in the table.  I would like to do this without attaching a class to every td in the table, is there a way to select an entire column using jQuery?  Below is an example of the HTML.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th class="col1">Header 1</th><th class="col2">Header 2</th><th class="col3">Header 3</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td></tr>
</table>

<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="col1" checked="checked" /> Hide/Show Column 1 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="col2" checked="checked" /> Hide/Show Column 2 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="col3" checked="checked" /> Hide/Show Column 3 <br />
</form>
```

Comment: I hope the folowing site would help: http://www.fiendish.demon.co.uk/html/javascript/hidetablecols.html

Comment: I implemented this solution using jQuery, and it worked perfectly for me: [http://www.devcurry.com/2009/07/hide-table-column-with-single-line-of.html](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/07/hide-table-column-with-single-line-of.html)

Comment: Per user344059's comment, here's the web archive for the broken link [http://www.fiendish.demon.co.uk/html/javascript/hidetablecols.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20150725122312/http://www.fiendish.demon.co.uk/html/javascript/hidetablecols.html)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

> I would like to do this without attaching a class to every td

Personally, I would go with the the class-on-each-td/th/col approach. Then you can switch columns on and off using a single write to className on the container, assuming style rules like:

```
table.hide1 .col1 { display: none; }
table.hide2 .col2 { display: none; }
...
```

This is going to be faster than any JS loop approach; for really long tables it can make a significant difference to responsiveness.

If you can get away with not supporting IE6, you could use adjacency selectors to avoid having to add the class attributes to tds. Or alternatively, if your concern is making the markup cleaner, you could add them from JavaScript automatically in an initialisation step.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I had wanted to keep the HTML cleaner, but performance definitely became an issue as the table size approached 100 rows.  This solution, provided a 2-5x performance improvement.

Comment: This approach worked wonders for me, performance-wise. Thanks!

Comment: I added this to my css `.hidden {display:none;}` and used `.addClass('hidden')` and `.removeClass('hidden')` which was a little faster than `.hide()` and `.show()`.

Answer (score 274):

One line of code using jQuery which hides the 2nd column:

```
$('td:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

If your table has header(th), use this:

```
$('td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

Source: [Hide a Table Column with a Single line of jQuery code](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/07/hide-table-column-with-single-line-of.html)

jsFiddle to test the code: http://jsfiddle.net/mgMem/1/

---

If you want to see a good use case, take a look at my blog post:

[Hide a table column and colorize rows based on value with jQuery](http://www.leniel.net/2012/03/hide-webgrid-column-colorize-rows-value.html).

Comment: As an aside as they're not in the example, is there not an issue that this ignores colspans? Good if you're not using them though.

There's another question related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166452/finding-column-index-using-jquery-when-table-contains-column-spanning-cells/1166639#comment9684733_1166639

Comment: I had to add the tbody to the selector to avoid hiding the footer with the pager: $('.webgrid tbody td:nth-child(1), .webgrid th:nth-child(1)').hide();

Comment: @KimR This may help for colspan issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623601/how-to-use-class-attribute-in-html-col/9623761#9623761

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but I had to use 'nth-of-type' instead, to make it work. For example: $('table td:nth-of-type(2)').hide();

Comment: @LeopoldoSanczyk were you using Safari? Seems like it needs nth-of-type

Comment: @ykay I forgotten to mention I was using Firefox. Judging by the date, 32.0.X or a close version.

Comment: @LeopoldoSanczyk Ok, I asked because I just ran into that when a client asked for his site to work on safari. Perhaps the same for firefox as well

Comment: Careful: when getting the index with `$('.mycol').closest('th').index()` you have to add 1 because `nth-child` starts at 1!!! so `colIdx = $('.mycol').closest('th').index() + 1`

Comment: does this affect every table in the page?

Comment: @golimar yes... to restrict that, you need to add a CSS class to the table you want to target. Something as: `.my-table-class td:nth-child(2)`

Answer (score 19):

Here's a little more fully featured answer that provides some user interaction on a per column basis.  If this is going to be a dynamic experience, there needs to be a clickable toggle on each column that indicates the ability to hide the column, and then a way to restore previously hidden columns.

That would look something like this in JavaScript:

```js
$('.hide-column').click(function(e){
  var $btn = $(this);
  var $cell = $btn.closest('th,td')
  var $table = $btn.closest('table')

  // get cell location - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4999018/1366033
  var cellIndex = $cell[0].cellIndex + 1;

  $table.find(".show-column-footer").show()
  $table.find("tbody tr, thead tr")
        .children(":nth-child("+cellIndex+")")
        .hide()
})

$(".show-column-footer").click(function(e) {
    var $table = $(this).closest('table')
    $table.find(".show-column-footer").hide()
    $table.find("th, td").show()

})
```

To support this, we'll add some markup to the table.  In each column header, we can add something like this to provide a visual indicator of something clickable

```html
<button class="pull-right btn btn-default btn-condensed hide-column" 
            data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Hide Column">
    <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>  
</button>
```

We'll allow the user to restore columns via a link in the table footer.  If it's not persistent by default, then toggling it on dynamically in the header could jostle around the table, but you can really put it anywhere you'd like:

```html
<tfoot class="show-column-footer">
   <tr>
    <th colspan="4"><a class="show-column" href="#">Some columns hidden - click to show all</a></th>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

That's the basic functionality. Here's a demo below with a couple more things fleshed out. You can also add a tooltip to the button to help clarify its purpose, style the button a little more organically to a table header, and collapse the column width in order to add some (somewhat wonky) css animations to make the transition a little less jumpy.

[image: Demo Screengrab]

#### Working Demo in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/rr96p4vv/) & Stack Snippets:

```js
$(function() {
  // on init
  $(".table-hideable .hide-col").each(HideColumnIndex);

  // on click
  $('.hide-column').click(HideColumnIndex)

  function HideColumnIndex() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var $cell = $el.closest('th,td')
    var $table = $cell.closest('table')

    // get cell location - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4999018/1366033
    var colIndex = $cell[0].cellIndex + 1;

    // find and hide col index
    $table.find("tbody tr, thead tr")
      .children(":nth-child(" + colIndex + ")")
      .addClass('hide-col');
      
    // show restore footer
    $table.find(".footer-restore-columns").show()
  }

  // restore columns footer
  $(".restore-columns").click(function(e) {
    var $table = $(this).closest('table')
    $table.find(".footer-restore-columns").hide()
    $table.find("th, td")
      .removeClass('hide-col');

  })

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    trigger: 'hover'
  })

})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
}

.table-hideable td,
.table-hideable th {
  width: auto;
  transition: width .5s, margin .5s;
}

.btn-condensed.btn-condensed {
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-shadow: none;
}


/* use class to have a little animation */
.hide-col {
  width: 0px !important;
  height: 0px !important;
  display: block !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/paper/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-hideable">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Controller
        <button class="pull-right btn btn-default btn-condensed hide-column" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Hide Column">
          <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>  
        </button>
      </th>
      <th class="hide-col">
        Action
        <button class="pull-right btn btn-default btn-condensed hide-column" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Hide Column">
          <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>  
        </button>
      </th>
      <th>
        Type
        <button class="pull-right btn btn-default btn-condensed hide-column" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Hide Column">
          <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>  
        </button>
      </th>
      <th>
        Attributes
        <button class="pull-right btn btn-default btn-condensed hide-column" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Hide Column">
          <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>  
        </button>
      </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Home</td>
      <td>Index</td>
      <td>ActionResult</td>
      <td>Authorize</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Client</td>
      <td>Index</td>
      <td>ActionResult</td>
      <td>Authorize</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Client</td>
      <td>Edit</td>
      <td>ActionResult</td>
      <td>Authorize</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  <tfoot class="footer-restore-columns">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4"><a class="restore-columns" href="#">Some columns hidden - click to show all</a></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: you are hiding nearest 1 column,how to hide nearest 3 column ?

Comment: check my table - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA8iZ.png  and question which contain table html - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838119/how-to-loop-multiple-table-th-in-angularjs button will come after A,B and C

Comment: sorry to revive such an old answer, but is there an easy way of setting certain columns to hidden by default? I'm trying to do so with `$(document).ready` but having no luck

Comment: @RobotJohnny, good question. This is using the class `.hide-col` to remove columns, but it can also be used to indicate state as well, so you could either - add `.hide-col` to each `td` & `tr` when rendering the html and be done.  Or if you wanted to add it in fewer places, put it in the header (that state will have to go somewhere), and on init, use that to hide that column index across children.  Currently, the code is just listening for the the position on click, but it could be modified to look for class position as well.  Also, happy turkey day

Comment: @RobotJohnny, I updated the code sample to include initialization handling as well.  Just drop `class='hide-col'` anywhere you want in your html (probably in in the `thead > tr > th` makes the most sense and it will pick up to make sure it hides all cells in that column and dynamically show the restore footer as well

Comment: How can I keep column width fixed when any column is hidden?

Comment: @sjain, the table in the demo has the width set to `100%` so when columns are removed, the others will occupy that space.  One way is to not have tables fill 100% width, and then each of the columns will size independently and retain their width no matter which are visible.  Here's an [example of that approach in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/rr96p4vv/386/)

Answer (score 12):

you could use colgroups:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
       <col class="visible_class"/>
       <col class="visible_class"/>
       <col class="invisible_class"/>  
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr><th class="col1">Header 1</th><th class="col2">Header 2</th><th class="col3">Header 3</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td></tr>
</table>
```

your script then could change just the desire `<col>` class.

Comment: I seem to remember colgroup not having cross browser support is that no longer true?

Comment: Maybe. i'm using this method for hilight columns, (firefox, safari, chrome works fine) never tried it in IE.

Comment: @Brian - IE8 does not work and IE8 with IE7 enabled seems to be working.

Comment: This seems not to work anymore in modern browser (Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: @JBE: to be precise, this *does* work in modern browsers *to some extent*. Using the `$('table > colgroup > col.yourClassHere')` jQuery selector, you still can set smth like the background color of the whole column, but you're no longer able to toggle column visibility. Browsers tested were MSIE **11**, Safari **5**, Chromium **44**, Opera **12**, Mozilla SeaMonkey **2.40**, Mozilla Firefox **43**. "Most of the attributes in HTML 4.01 are not supported in HTML5" -- see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_colgroup.asp).

Answer (score 11):

The following should do it:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    var index = $(this).attr('name').substr(2);
    $('table tr').each(function() { 
        $('td:eq(' + index + ')',this).toggle();
    });
});
```

This is untested code, but the principle is that you choose the table cell in each row that corresponds to the chosen index extracted from the checkbox name. You could of course limit the selectors with a class or an ID.

Answer (score 5):

And of course, the CSS only way for [browsers that support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) `nth-child`:

`table td:nth-child(2) { display: none; }`

This is for IE9 and newer.

For your usecase, you'd need several classes to hide the columns:

```
.hideCol1 td:nth-child(1) { display: none;}
.hideCol2 td:nth-child(2) { display: none;}
```

ect...

Answer (score 2):

The following is building on Eran's code, with a few minor changes. Tested it and it seems to work fine on Firefox 3, IE7.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        var index = $(this).attr('name').substr(3);
        index--;
        $('table tr').each(function() { 
            $('td:eq(' + index + ')',this).toggle();
        });
        $('th.' + $(this).attr('name')).toggle();
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col1">Header 1</th>
        <th class="col2">Header 2</th>
        <th class="col3">Header 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td></tr>
</table>

<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="col1" checked="checked" /> Hide/Show Column 1 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="col2" checked="checked" /> Hide/Show Column 2 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="col3" checked="checked" /> Hide/Show Column 3 <br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="ch1" checked="checked" /> First Name</p>
.... 
<td class="ch1">...</td>

 <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#demo').multiselect();
        });


        $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).hide();
});

$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).toggle();
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without class? You can use the Tag then:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('TD'),i;
for (i in tds) {
  tds[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

And to show them use:

```
...style.display = 'table-cell';
```