# Using objective c and xpath find column index when table contains column spanning cells

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, xpath, libxml2

Im parsing a table using hpple and libxml2 in an iPhone app.  I have encountered a real problem when it comes to finding the column index when sibling cells span multiple rows using colspan.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166452/finding-column-index-using-jquery-when-table-contains-column-spanning-cells)
But I can't use jquery to work out the column.

Consider the following table

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td id="example1">Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td>Six</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">One</td>
      <td colspan="2">Two</td>
      <td colspan="2" id="example2">Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td>Six</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can i get the column index as 6 NOT 3 for the cell with id 'example1'?

EDIT Added more detail

```
NSString *xpathQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 
+ count(//a[contains(@href,'testHref')]
/../preceding-sibling::td[not(@colspan)])
+ sum(//a[contains(@href,'testHref')]/../preceding-sibling::td/@colspan)
+ sum(@colspan)
- count(@colspan)",bookingUrl, bookingUrl];

//Execute XPath
NSArray *array = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:columnCount];
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
1 + count(preceding-sibling::td[not(@colspan)])
+ sum(preceding-sibling::td/@colspan)
+ sum(@colspan)
- count(@colspan)
```

Running the xpath for the `<td>` as the current node.

Comment: My problem is that Hpple expressions return an array of Nodes. Also, how I identify the cells is a little more complicated... I've added more code to my answer