# Select table cells based on the value in the cell

Tags: jquery

I have a table as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/UqdQp/4/. I need to set background color as red for all columns that has value “1”.  What is the best way (in terms of performance) for doing this using jQuery?

Note: After doing the background color, I need to alert the value of the table cell also. That means I need to use “this” operator on the selected cell.

**Reference Answers:**

1. http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/uGKHB/11/
2. http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/uGKHB/12/
3. [Finding column index using jQuery when table contains column-spanning cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166452/finding-column-index-using-jquery-when-table-contains-column-spanning-cells)

Comment: All columns that contain *a* 1, or all columns for which all contained values (with the exception of the header row) *are* 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $tds = $("td").filter(function(i){
    return $(this).html() == 1;
});

$tds.css({ background: 'red' });

$.each($tds, function(i, x){
    console.log($(x).html());
});
```

I used console.log instead of alert for obvious reasons.

Comment: It does coloring for "1234" also. How can we overcome this? http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/uGKHB/3/

Comment: Thanks. I tried to apply this to header cell - did not work. Any idea why? http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/uGKHB/7/

Comment: `return $.trim($(this).html()) == 'Type';` -- you have to trim the whitespace out. http://jsfiddle.net/uGKHB/9/

Comment: Thanks. Answers are available in http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/uGKHB/11/ and http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/uGKHB/10/

Answer (score 1):

I have used the `each` function of jQuery to iterate over each table cells and highlight the cell when it matches the required condition.
Working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/saji89/uGKHB/

```
$('.resultGridTable td').each(function()
{
    if($(this).html()==1)
    {
        $(this).css({'background':'#FF0000'});
    }        
});
```

Using `contains` selector instead of `if` conditional, should be more faster:
http://jsfiddle.net/saji89/WbXTr/

Comment: Please post your answer in your answer, rather than relying on an external site to host your code.

Comment: Thanks. It works. However I wonder whether there is a more fast way.

Comment: Check this out, uses `contains` selector, and thereby avoids the `if` usage:http://jsfiddle.net/saji89/WbXTr/