# Get Index of a td considering the colspan using jquery

Tags: jquery

"I want the index of id:Second to be 2(Considering #First as 2 columns). But with the help of `$("#Second").parent().find("td").index($("#Second"))` i get 1. Any Direct function in Jquery to do this without i having to use FOR LOOPS or .each function or any sort of loop???"

```
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" id="First">
</td>
<td colspan="2" id="Second">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Any Direct function in Jquery to do this without i having to use FOR LOOPS or .each function or any sort of loop???"

No, I don't believe there is. The loop is trivial, of course.

```
var index = 0;
$("#Second").prevAll("td").each(function() {
    index += this.colSpan;
});
console.log(index);
```

Output:

```
2
```

...which is the 0-based index of that cell, including colspans.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/lola/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/lola/1/edit)

Similarly, with this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>One column wide</td>
        <td colspan="2">Two columns wide</td>
        <td>One column wide</td>
        <td colspan="2" id="Last">Two columns wide</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

That code gives us `4` for the last column (the 0-based index of the 5th column). [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/lola/3) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/lola/3/edit)

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166452/finding-column-index-using-jquery-when-table-contains-column-spanning-cells/26896740#26896740 
I love how concise this is, thanks.