# Collapse/Expand table columns (not rows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a large report currently rendered as a regular HTML table. I'd like to be able to group columns together and expand/collapse them with a button.

This is a very common practice for rows but not so much for columns. I was wondering if anyone has any tips for doing it with columns.

My stack includes jquery so that's available to you (though certainly not required!).

Comment: Apparently the keywords I was missing in my search were "show/hide". Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455958/hide-show-column-in-an-html-table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [columnManager](http://p.sohei.org/jquery-plugins/columnmanager/) plugin. Can't be easier.

Comment: Could you please click the check box to accept this answer :P

Comment: Accepted (I was holding out to see if other answers would come in...)