# Collapsing the column of the table

Tags: jquery

I do have a table of 5 columns.i want to collapse last three columns of the table on click of a image and again reappear on click of other image.I have written some code but its not working so please guide me on this:

```
<img id="hide" src="assets/img/decrease_indent.png" />
        <img id="show" src="assets/img/increase_indent.png" />

<thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="">Name</th>
                    <th class=""></th>
                    <th class="">Dur</th>
                    <th class="">Start</th>
                    <th class=""></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach:items">
                <tr  data-bind="value:id">
                    <td data-bind="text:"></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td  data-bind="text:"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text:"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text:"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>



    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
        $("#hide").live('click',function(){
        $("th:eq(2),th:eq(3),th:eq(4)td:eq(2),td:eq(3),td:eq(4)").hide();
        });
        $("#show").live('click',function(){
        $("th:eq(2),th:eq(3),th:eq(4)td:eq(2),td:eq(3),td:eq(4)").show();
        });
});
        </script>
```

Comment: Your jQuery code should be wrapped inside `$(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
 });`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Collapse/Expand table columns (not rows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511677/collapse-expand-table-columns-not-rows)

Comment: your table content should be wrapped inside `<table> your table content goes here </table>`

Comment: yes that much i know if u do have a answer then reply @Muleskinner

Comment: Note that `.live` is no longer supported in the latest versions of jQuery. Hard to tell if that is the problem as you do not mention which version you use. Could you post your code (including your valid html) to jsfiddle?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "_..its not working.._"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/LTj2n/)**

```
//To hide
$('th:gt(2)').hide();
$('td:gt(2)').hide();

//To show
$('th:gt(2)').show();
$('td:gt(2)').show();
```

Edit based on comments

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/uzoker/2/edit)**

Comment: but due to this code my 1st row is getting collapsed.i want to do this with last three rows

Comment: Do you want to collapse columns or rows? check the statement in question "i want to collapse last three columns of the table"

Comment: What does this mean in your previous comment "but due to this code my 1st row is getting collapsed.i want to do this with last three rows"

Comment: that means my all 5 table headings are getting collapsed that means entire 1st row

Comment: In dome all the columns are not collapsing ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23900/discussion-between-santosh-mishra-and-adil)

Answer (score 0):

You miss a comma between `th:eq(4)` and `td:eq(2)` in both hide and show.

A working example based on your code can be seen here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/r5LuV/).

Note that as you are using `.live` you cannot use the latest version of jQuery.