# jquery not selecting header element when browser back button clicked in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, webgrid

I have an MVC3 webgrid where the first column is being hidden by jQuery with the following code as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5901376/265877):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//hide the first column in the result table
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.webgrid thead th:nth-child(1)').hide();
    $('.webgrid tbody td:nth-child(1)').hide();
});
```

The code works great except for one thing. The header element doesn't always get hidden if I navigate away from the page and come back by hitting the browser's back button in IE9 (Chrome & Firefox don't seem to have this problem).  Interestingly, the td elements in tbody DO get hidden. I used jQuery 1.5.1 and now just tried 1.7.1 with no improvement. Refreshing the page fixes the problem. Any ideas why this is happening or how I should go about investigating what's going on?  Thanks!

### Update

I took out the code that hides the column, and I STILL get the bug on the back browse!!!  I tried cleaning out the cache and still the same.  Where is this old broken page coming from?  I tried IE in-private browsing and the problem went away, but when I came back to regular browsing the problem came back! I cleaned the cache 10 times! Why is it not working?

Comment: Where in the page is this code you included in your question?

Comment: I updated the code section to answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it was a problem with the cache.  IE9 has a checkbox to "preserve favorites website data" and I had that checked with all the other items. As soon as I unchecked it everything worked great!  Reference [this article](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=15141) for clearing cache.

Comment: So, you were running old code and the posted code works?  I was wondering if maybe you weren't running it on load, which you are.

Comment: yea, the code was right.  It was just an caching problem.  IE9 delete cache options specifically.