# Remove column from specific table with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using a CMS that doesn't let me edit the HTML, I can only use JavaScript and HTML to customize the way it looks. There's a page with 3 tables and I want to remove (or hide) the **2nd column from the 2nd table**. Here's the HTML code:

```
<TABLE>
   <TR>
      <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
   </TR>
</TABLE>

<TABLE>
   <TR>
      <TH>Row 1</TH>
      <TH>Row 2</TH>
      <TH>Row 3</TH>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
   </TR>
</TABLE>

<TABLE>
   <TR>
      <TH>Row 1</TH>
      <TH>Row 2</TH>
      <TH>Row 3</TH>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
   </TR>
</TABLE>
```

How do I remove JUST the second column in the second table?

Comment: Since you have tagged this with jquery, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455958/hide-show-column-in-an-html-table

Comment: I've looked at similar questions, but the problem I'm having is targeting just the 2nd table. I can't edit the HTML, so I can only use jQuery to target it. How do you select the 2nd column in the 2nd table only without selecting the other 2 tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FJfbW/1/

```
$('td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2)', 'table:eq(1) tr').css('background', '#f00');
```

​

You can use `.remove()` without using `.css()` to get rid of the column

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/upeVs/

```
$('table:eq(1) tr td:nth-child(2),table:eq(1) tr th:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

**Edit:**
Solution given by `@blackpla9ue` is maybe a little bit more performant given that it only once looks for the table row:

```
$('td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2)', 'table:eq(1) tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that the tables do not have ids. So @blackpla9ue's answer is the most appropriate. But if you need to remove the second row of a table which has an id then go for the below code.

```
$('td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2)', '#tblEventSearchResults tr').css('background', '#f00');​
```