# How to hide a column in the Webgrid in aspasp.net MVC?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and I use `Webgrid` to display some customer values.
I need to hide columns together with their headers. How do i do this?

CSS: `gridhide {   visibility:hidden  }`
 Code: `grid.Column("Id", "ID", style: "gridhide"),`

Comment: Assuming you meant give the column a class name you're missing the `.` in the `.gridhide` css selector

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hide particular column:
Please Try This:
`WEBGRID`

```
grid.Column(null,null, format: @<input type="hidden" name="IDHidden" value="@item.IDHidden"/>),
```

Comment: this almost works for me but seems to leave a tiny blank column in my table where the column has been excluded

Answer (score 2):

I ended up [using jQuery to hide the column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5901376/74585) on the client side. Not ideal but easy to implement. Eg to hide the second column:

```
$('td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

Another option would be to simply not add the column to the grid in the first place like so, as seen here:  https://forums.asp.net/post/5850519.aspx

```
var books = db.Query(sql);
var columns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
columns.Add(new WebGridColumn(){ColumnName = "BookId", Header = "Book Id" });
if(books.Any(b =>b.Price != null)){
    columns.Add(new WebGridColumn(){ColumnName = "Price", Header = "Price" });
}
var grid = new WebGrid(books);
```

Answer (score 0):

`gridhide` is a class, define `class` instead of `style` in `grid.column`

Comment: The column values will hide..still header is on display i want to hide even header also

Comment: define class on header.

Comment: I use this code to hide column grid.Column(null,null, format: @<input type="hidden" name="IDHidden" value="@item.IDHidden"/>),