# How to toggle table column?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle a table column by providing a button in the header of every column, when user clicks on the button that specific column should be hidden and when user clicks it again it should open. But my problem is as i am hiding the whole column when user clicks on the button in the header user is not able to see the button. Can anyone suggest me how this can be achieved using jquery?

You can see the image as below

[image]

Thanks,

Praveen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide/Show Column in an HTML Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455958/hide-show-column-in-an-html-table)

Comment: This seems not a jquery related problem, but a logical problem. If you hide the column including the button, obviously you can't click the button anymore. How to solve it? Don't hide the button.

Comment: Shrink the column width, rather than hiding it

Comment: Give a small set of checkboxes that decide what to show or not

Comment: kyo: Any pointers on show we can shrink the column?

Answer (score 0):

[Table column hide or display](http://jsfiddle.net/mgMem/671/)

The best solution to the problem is place your button in th

### jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnHide').click(function() {
                $('td:nth-child(1)').toggle();
                
            });
        });
```

[image: Toggle]

[Check out second case](http://jsfiddle.net/mgMem/673/)

[Solved Checkout](http://jsfiddle.net/mgMem/676/)

Comment: Can you check the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/mgMem/672/
I made some changes, what i want is when user clicks on toggle button the second column should not move under toggle button.

Comment: exactly what you want please specify in a detailed manner i will get it done

Comment: do you want your column to remain under corressponding th when hide is clicked

Comment: As you can see in the updated fiddle when i click on "toggle" button on the first column as we are hiding the first td the second td is occupying the space under first td, but i dont want the second td to be moved under first td. And there should be empty space under "toggle" button.
Jsfiddle FYR:
http://jsfiddle.net/mgMem/672/

Comment: Yeah that was exactly what i asked above let mee c 5 mins

Comment: I have solved the issue by hiding the children using jquery Child selector instead hiding the whole column. Thanks for your inputs though.