# Filter a html table using dropdown colum list by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

I have a jQuery script that filters the html table having many columns, i just need to be able to show all the rows based on user input, but only want the filtering of the table should go through specific column selected by user from dropdown list

**jQuery code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#kwd_search").keyup(function(){
      var term=$(this).val()
      if( term != "")
      {
        $("#my-table tbody>tr").hide();
        $("#my-table td").filter(function(){
               return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term ) >-1
        }).parent("tr").show();
       $("#my-table tbody>tr th").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#my-table tbody>tr").show();
      }
   });
});
```

**Html Code**

```
<select id="clmn_name">
 <option>Column 1</option>
 <option>Column 2</option>
 <option>Column 3</option>
</select>

<input id="kwd_search" placeholder="Search Me">

<table id="my-table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Column 1</th>
     <th>Column 2</th>
     <th>Column 3</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Mango</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
     <td>Strawberry</td>
     <td>Banana</td>
     <td>Cherry</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

So how can the returned HTML code be filtered as per the table column selected by user?

Comment: I m also looking for a same kind of solution.....

Comment: so whats the problem it working fine?

Comment: i guess this question has what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455958/hide-show-column-in-an-html-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `selectedIndex` property of the select element for filtering the target cells:

```
$("#kwd_search").keyup(function () {
    var index = $('#clmn_name').prop('selectedIndex'),
        term = $.trim(this.value);

    if (term.length === 0) {
        $("#my-table tbody > tr").show();
        return;
    }

    $("#my-table tbody > tr").hide().filter(function () {
        return this.cells[index].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1;
    }).show();

});
```

In case that you want to listen to change event of the select element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Caching the elements and binding handlers
    var $s = $('#clmn_name').on('change', filterRows),
        $i = $("#kwd_search").on('keyup', filterRows),
        $rows = $("#my-table tbody > tr");

    function filterRows() {
        var ind = $s.prop('selectedIndex'),
            term = $.trim($i.val().toLowerCase());

        if (term.length === 0) return $rows.show();

        $rows.hide().filter(function () {
            return this.cells[ind].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1;
        }).show();

    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jaeq6v0u/

The jQuerish way of selecting the target cells will be:

```
return $('td', this).eq(index).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1;
```

Comment: Ahhh.....u r awesome brother.....thank u....that's like the way i want to filter the table.....thank u again.....

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Searchtxt').on('input', function (e) {
                var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        var columnIndex=0;
                $("#dataTableBody tr").filter(function () {
                    $(this).toggle($(this).children(":eq(" + columnIndex + ")").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) >`enter code here` -1)
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you provide some context to explain your code and why your answer works?