# Can't display a third column in my HTML table (drilldown functionality jQuery / JavaScript )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on this HTML Table with drilldown functionality, it works for one column but I cant display a third column, I want to click on subcategory column and display another column but Im stuck in this part .

This is my JS code

```
         function toggleVisibilitySubcategory() {

        $('table.drillDown th:nth-child(2)').toggle();
        $('table.drillDown tbody td:nth-child(2)').toggle();
    }

    function toggleVisibilityItem() {

        $('table.drillDown th:nth-child(3)').toggle();
        $('table.drillDown tbody td:nth-child(3)').toggle();
    }

    $(function () {
        toggleVisibilitySubcategory();
        toggleVisibilityItem();
        $('table.drillDown').each(function() {

            var $table = $(this);
            $table.find('.parent').click(function() {
                console.log( "click on parent" );
                $(this).nextUntil('.parent').toggle();

                if ($(this).find("td:hidden").length > 0) {
                    toggleVisibilitySubcategory();
                }

            });

            var $childRows = $table.find('tbody tr').not('.parent').hide();
            $table.find('button.hide').click(function() {
                $childRows.hide();
            });
            $table.find('button.show').click(function() {
                $childRows.filter('.child').show();
            });
            $table.find('tr.child').click(function(){
                $(this).nextUntil('.child').show()
            });


        });
    });
```

This is the HTML table.

```
 <table class="drillDown" border="1" align="center">

    <thead>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Subcategory</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>LW</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <!--PARENT ROW-->
     <tr class="parent">
      <td>Category 1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>

     <tr class="child" >
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Subcategory_1 A
      <td>a</td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>

     <tr class="child">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Subcategory_1 B</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: your html is off your thead is closed after you colgroup

Comment: Thank's for the edition!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide/Show Column in an HTML Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455958/hide-show-column-in-an-html-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to create a new toggle function to hide/show last table column and use it likes in the followig snippet:

```js
function toggleVisibilitySubcategory() {
  $('table.drillDown th:nth-child(2)').toggle();
  $('table.drillDown tbody td:nth-child(2)').toggle();
}
$(function () {
  toggleVisibilitySubcategory();
  $('table.drillDown').each(function() {

    var $table = $(this);
    $table.find('.parent').click(function() {
      console.log( "*****Click on Parent" );
      $(this).nextUntil('.parent').toggle();
      if ($(this).find("td:hidden").length == 1) {
        toggleVisibilitySubcategory();
      }
    });

    var $childRows = $table.find('tbody tr').not('.parent').hide();
    $table.find('button.hide').click(function() {
      $childRows.hide();
    });
    $table.find('button.show').click(function() {
      $childRows.filter('.child').show();
    });
    $table.find('tr.child').click(function(){
      $(this).nextUntil('.child').show()
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<table class="drillDown" border="1" align="center">
    <colgroup>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Subcategory</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
    <!--PARENT ROW-->
    <tr class="parent">
        <td>Category 1</td>
        <td colspan="2">$12,345.45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child" >
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">Subcategory_1 A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">Subcategory_1 B</td>
    </tr>
    <!--PARENT ROW-->
    <tr class="parent">
        <td>Category 2</td>
        <td colspan="2">$135,754.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child" >
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">Subcategory_2 A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">Subcategory_2 B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">Subcategory_2 C</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="parent">
        <td>Catgegory 3</td>
        <td colspan="2">$232,563.46</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child" >
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">Subcategory_3 A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">Subcategory_3 B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">Subcategory_3 C</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for your help, I'm not familiar with this property " th:nth-child(2)" but this works perfect for me.   

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: Also i'm gonna check the js code to understand it, if I have a question I'll come back to you, I'm kind of new to JS

Comment: The meaning of th:nth-child(2) is: Second table header while using td:nth-child(2) you get all the Second column cells. It's hard to understand at beginning this type of selector filter but you can take a look on MDN

Comment: Sorry, instead of MDN you have to take a look at jQuery.com --- API --- selector and filter

Comment: Thank's a lot for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this: https://jsfiddle.net/az0w2c8a/

```
$('.drillDown tr td:last-child, .drillDown tr th:last-child').hide();

$('.drillDown tr td:first-child, .drillDown tr th:first-child').click(function(){
    $('.drillDown tr td:last-child, .drillDown tr th:last-child').show();
})
```

Alternatively if you need to add additional columns to your table you can use either ':nth-child()'

```
$('.drillDown tr td:nth-child(2), .drillDown tr th:nth-child(2)').hide();

$('.drillDown tr td:first-child, .drillDown tr th:first-child').click(function(){
    $('.drillDown tr td:nth-child(2), .drillDown tr th:nth-child(2)').show();
})
```

if you need to hide all columns except the first one you can use the '.not()' method.

```
$('.drillDown tr td, .drillDown tr th').not(':first-child').hide();

    $('.drillDown tr td:first-child, .drillDown tr th:first-child').click(function(){
    $('.drillDown tr td, .drillDown tr th').not(':first-child').show();
})
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfect for me!

I was telling to gaemaf that I was not familiar with this property "th:nth-child(2)"

But this help a lot!

Thank's

Comment: Hi there!

One more question, What if I need an extra hidden column next to Subcategory column.

Comment: @KennethEspinal see my edit for additional hidden columns. The '.not()' method is easiest as long as there are not any columns other than the first one you want to show.

Comment: Hi Gregg, thank's for your time!  I put my code in here https://jsfiddle.net/kennechu/b59zqc5t/2/ 

What I understand of the .not() method is that it will show the two hidden columns at the same time, but what I want to achive is show one column at a time, when I click on Category it will display Subcategory, when I click on a Subcategory it will display a third column, at this moment the Subcategory will be a "parent" for third column and it will continue a child column for Category. I dont know if you get my idea.