# How to loop multiple Table TH in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
  <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th colspan="3" ng-repeat="d in $ctrl.otherdata">{{d.name}}</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>User ID</th>
     ***** want to loop following 3 th***** 
     <th>ABC</th>
     <th>XYZ</th>
     <th>PQR</th>
    ***************************************
   </tr>

</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="data in $ctrl.somedata">
     <td>{{data.name}}</td>
     <td>{{data.x}}</td>
     <td>{{data.y}}</td>
     <td>{{data.z}}</td>

   </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Is it possible to loop following 3 th in ng-repeat based on length of `$ctrl.otherdata`?

```
<th>ABC</th>
<th>XYZ</th>
<th>PQR</th>
```

I tried but look like it is against web standard, I tried using DIV but look like  it is not possible in table so any other alternative ?

Check attached image : this is what i am looking for throw loop using angular js

[image: I want table like this using loop]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work -

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
  <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th colspan="3" ng-repeat="din $ctrl.otherdata">{{d.name}}</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>User ID</th>
      <th ng-repeat-start="x in $ctrl.otherdata">ABC</th>
      <th>XYZ</th>
      <th ng-repeat-end>PQR</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in $ctrl.somedata">
      <td>{{data.name}}</td>
      <td>{{data.x}}</td>
      <td>{{data.y}}</td>
      <td>{{data.z}}</td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Excellent ! Great Answer ! Thank You !

Comment: Glad that it helped :)