# How to make html table columns (<th>) collapsible/expandable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, datatables

I looked everywhere for an answer to this and couldn't find anything. I have an HTML table with 13 columns. My 7th column *Number of Tops* is a grand total of columns 8-11: *# Short-sleeve, # Long-sleeve, # Sweaters, # Jackets*. Each row in the table represents a person's clothes that they own. My goal is to have columns 8-11 collapsed by default and only display columns 1-7 and columns 12 and 13. When I click on the 7th column's header `<th>Number of Tops</th>`, I want columns 8-11 to expand to show more information about the how that number is broken down. Additionally, when the columns are expanded, clicking the 7th column's header `<th>Number of Tops</th>` should make the expanded columns 8-11 collapse again. Ideally I'd like to make a nice CSS transition when the columns expand/collapse, but that's just the cherry on top.

Heres the HTML of the table I'm talking about:

```html
<div class="table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>             <!-- Always visible -->
        <th>Address</th>          <!-- Always visible -->
        <th>Phone Number</th>     <!-- Always visible -->
        <th>Number of Pants</th>  <!-- Always visible -->
        <th>Number of Shoes</th>  <!-- Always visible -->
        <th>Number of Socks</th>  <!-- Always visible -->
        <!-- Column 7: totals column -->
        <th>Number of Tops</th>   <!-- Always visible; clickable -->
        <th># Short-sleeve</th>   <!-- collapsible/expandable -->
        <th># Long-sleeve</th>    <!-- collapsible/expandable -->
        <th># Sweaters</th>       <!-- collapsible/expandable -->
        <th># Jackets</th>        <!-- collapsible/expandable -->
        <th>Number of Hats</th>   <!-- Always visible -->
        <th>Number of Bags</th>   <!-- Always visible -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

When the columns are collapsed, I want the corresponding cell values for columns 8-11 to also collapse as if CSS `display: none`. So it looks like a normal table with 9 columns until the 7th column header is clicked, which will transition columns 8-11 to open/expand from the right side into a 13-column table. Then when clicked again, columns 8-11 should transition a collapse left "into" the right side of the 7th column. The columns should be in the same order as it was given.

I'd like to do this with pure HTML, Javascript, jQuery, and CSS if possible. The table is a DataTable.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you look here to get you started: [Hide/Show Column in a HTML Table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/455958/12567365). Also [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+table+column+show+hide+site%253Astackoverflow.com) may help.

Comment: Your update mentions "_The table is a DataTable_". So there are [all these official column visibility examples](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/index.html) that you can explore.

Comment: Is the content of cols 8-11 just text or are there images or anything else in there?

Comment: @andrewJames Thanks, that link was very resourceful. When I ran my project, I got this error: "Cannot extend unknown button type: clovisGroup" which I believe is coming from not having the correct DataTables/extensions versions. I tried downloading the correct versions using NPM as described on the Datatables download page, but I'm still getting the same errors. Any insights on how to fix this?

Comment: It's very difficult to help based on a description of the problem, stuffed into a comment. What would be better: Can you [edit] your question and add an update showing what you have tried and what goes wrong (in more detail). But... please try to provide the code and data as a [mre] with emphasis on "_minimal_" - only the least amount of code and data needed to allow us to _easily_ recreate your problem. You may even solve it yourself, in the process of creating your MRE.

Comment: Wait a minute - I just realized `clovisGroup` is actually `colvisGroup`, right? So, is that a typo somewhere in your code, perhaps? (An MRE would still be very helpful).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trivial example using font-size as the animatable property. It needs a line of JavaScript to set a class on the table itself so that the other cells in columns 8-11 can also pick up on expanding or contracting.

```css
table tr> :nth-child(8),
table tr> :nth-child(9),
table tr> :nth-child(10),
table tr> :nth-child(11) {
  font-size: 0px;
  transition: font-size 1s linear;
}

table.expand tr> :nth-child(8),
table.expand tr> :nth-child(9),
table.expand tr> :nth-child(10),
table.expand tr> :nth-child(11) {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <!-- Always visible -->
        <th>Address</th>
        <!-- Always visible -->
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <!-- Always visible -->
        <th>Number of Pants</th>
        <!-- Always visible -->
        <th>Number of Shoes</th>
        <!-- Always visible -->
        <th>Number of Socks</th>
        <!-- Always visible -->
        <!-- Column 7: totals column -->
        <th onclick="document.querySelector('table').classList.toggle('expand');">Number of Tops</th>
        <!-- Always visible; clickable -->
        <th># Short-sleeve</th>
        <!-- collapsible/expandable -->
        <th># Long-sleeve</th>
        <!-- collapsible/expandable -->
        <th># Sweaters</th>
        <!-- collapsible/expandable -->
        <th># Jackets</th>
        <!-- collapsible/expandable -->
        <th>Number of Hats</th>
        <!-- Always visible -->
        <th>Number of Bags</th>
        <!-- Always visible -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Fred</td>
        <!-- Always visible -->
        <td>Seattle</td>
        <!-- Always visible -->
        <td>07777777777</td>
        <!-- Always visible -->
        <td>4</td>
        <!-- Always visible -->
        <td>3</td>
        <!-- Always visible -->
        <td>24</td>
        <!-- Always visible -->
        <!-- Column 7: totals column -->
        <td>18</td>
        <!-- Always visible; -->
        <td>5</td>
        <!-- collapsible/expandable -->
        <td>6</td>
        <!-- collapsible/expandable -->
        <td>4</td>
        <!-- collapsible/expandable -->
        <td>3</th>
          <!-- collapsible/expandable -->
          <th>2</th>
          <!-- Always visible -->
          <th>4</th>
          <!-- Always visible -->
      </tr>
      <tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

However, you may want to be a little more sophisticated and use JS to find the actual widths of each of those columns and expand and contract them accordingly.